Mono.just and non-reactive spring boot
I've recently started working with Spring Boot in a new project that has the following code (simplified):
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class MyController {
  @Autowired 
  UserService service;
  @GetMapping 
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<User>> getUser() {

     // note, the non-reactive call is wrapped into Mono.just
     return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<User>(service.getUser(), ...);
  }
}
// both service and dao (below) are non reactive
@Service
public class UserService {
   @Autowired
   UserDao dao; 
   User getUser() {
     // some logic (everything is in memory, nothing is io-bound)
     return dao.getUser();
   }
}
@Repository
public class UserDao {
   public User getUser() {
      // call the non-reactive relational db and get the user
      // it takes 99% of the time I believe
      // return this user;
   }
}

Now I've never really used reactive approach but I understand that under-the-hood this spring boot application must run netty and use webflux
I've used a database as an example of I/O bound operation, but sometimes in the code there are also calls to remote services (REST), and also they're not reactive...
These DB operations/remote rest calls I believe take like 99% of the execution time, so this makes the application to be a good candidate for reactive implementation.
However, I'm confused by the current situation with the code:

The controller is reactive
The service / DAO / Remote Calls are not

My question is - whether such a usage of mixture of non-reactive and reactive approaches is ok or it is wrong?
In my understanding if I want to go with reactive web-flux approach, all my code must be reactive all the way down to the database/remote rest call (including them of course), otherwise I'll effectively keep the event-loop threads of netty busy and this is something I can't do... So it seems wrong to me in a nutshell, But I'm not sure what happens actually in this code. Is my understanding correct or I'm missing something?

You are right, you usually would want to go with full reactive all the way down until you do I/O. But underlying services does not need to be reactive. What tickles me in your question is the following: sometimes in the code there are also calls to remote services (REST), and also they're not reactive. This does not matter at all which paradigm are using underlying services. What mostly matters is that every non purely CPU actions are "valid" reactive-wise: either using non blocking drivers, or as @K.Nicholas said, by wrapping in a "reactive" compatible code block.

Just another question, can't you go full reactive? Do you have any constraint? If so, you could go with reactive driver and simply wrap non-reactive code in a reactive style paradigm, schedule it on a Schedulers.boundedElastic() and return the result of the Mono.subscribe() method.
Note that I would recommend to go reactive all the way, this should be a transitive solution or for very specific use cases I am not aware of.

Thanks Vincent, by mentioning the rest calls I meant that sometimes the flow calls other services of the application, and sometimes it queries the database. By non-reactive I meant the both are blocking calls, the thread that executes the call - waits till it gets a response. In general I just joined the project and the code as its written today seems wrong to me. I dont know whether I can go reactive because the actual database we use probably doesnt support reactive paradigm, so there is no reactive driver for it as I understand.

You could basically wrap your non-reactive calls in a Mono.fromCallable(() -> nonReactive()) following reactor's documentation. This way you can still use reactive paradigm in each of your entrypoints while still having a non reactive driver for your DB. I would further recommend you to adopt strategy pattern when a reactive drivers is released (if ever) for your specific database to allow you to switch from reactive to non-reactive easily.

Sucks that link doesn't get you to the correct documentation.

These DB operations/remote rest calls I believe take like 99% of the execution time, so this makes the application to be a good candidate for reactive implementation.
You will still have the same execution time. The Reactive frameworks is not for reducing execution time. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#getting-started-introducing-reactor.

Reactor is a fully non-blocking reactive programming foundation for the JVM, with efficient demand management (in the form of managing “backpressure”)

Is this your use case?
The controller is reactive
Really? You made it reactive with Mono::just but you're using non-reactive annotations.
The service / DAO / Remote Calls are not
Why not switch them as well? If you need to wrap them then check the docs. C.1. How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?.
In my understanding if I want to go with reactive web-flux approach, all my code must be reactive all the way down to the database/remote rest call (including them of course), otherwise I'll effectively keep the event-loop threads of netty busy and this is something I can't do... So it seems wrong to me in a nutshell, But I'm not sure what happens actually in this code. Is my understanding correct or I'm missing something?
Yes. All the way down. The purpose is to create a flow and pass it to the client. When the client requests the result the flow is executed within the reactive framework.
When the framework encounters a blocking call, DB or REST for example, it makes the call and repurposes the thread to execute another concurrent request. When the blocking call returns the thread is repurposed back to the original request. With apache tomcat using system threads you can handle maybe 1 or 2 thousand concurrent requests with very fine timing. Out of the box, 384. With WebFlux 30 to 50 thousand if you do it correctly. Do you have that many users that they will be making a steady 30K concurrent requests per second?
It's also wrapped up in the functional programming paradigm style. It's rare anyone writes good code with that paradigm. I just fixed a block of code that went 20 lines deep just to add a bunch of leaf nodes into a map. Replaced it with a couple forEach loops.
Have fun with this rabbit hole. People like the new stuff because it's exotic and fascinating. Wait until you need to maintain someone's code who didn't really understand the framework and it's purpose. Functional is just ugly and WebFlux is very obfuscated.
PS> Just to illustrate the point, Mono::just will execute the code first then build the flow with the result. It just places the result in a Mono, so in fact you have done nothing reactive whatsoever. So if you put a REST call in Mono.just it will invoke the endpoint before returning the flow to the client. Major reactive trap for beginners.

Thank you K.Nicholas. By calling the controller reactive I meant that using Mono abstraction pointed to me that under the hood it runs netty and uses webflux.... I don't think I just can use reactive approach because the actual db that we use doesnt support reactive way of work (no reactive driver). So I wanted to verify that my understanding is correct, and this way of code design is wrong. I personally think the same things you've said, but I didn't have much experience with reactive code...

Yea, no worries. It took me awhile to sort out what was going on with reactive. In the meantime Oracle has finished and published virtual threads so if you really want to handle thousands of concurrent requests the Async Servlet API and virtual threads is custom built for that. If you use it anyway it's best to understand it as a two step process. The first is to build the flow for a client, the second is the client executes it. The traps are 1) executing code while building as in the Mono.just 2) trying too hard to make everything functional when simple old java inside a map should be used.

@MarkBramnik If you don't have a reactive database driver then don't waste your time on Webflux. Just upgrade to Java 21 and use virtual threads instead. Note: you not only need a GOOD Spring compatible database driver, you may also need other components to support it like Spring itself, Hibernate, etc.

@MarkBramnik I.e. if you decided to use SQL and then wanted to use Webflux, you'd hate life. There IS a Reactive SQL driver, but it's extremely primitive, Hibernate doesn't support it either, so if you wanted to do anything more then flat 1:1 tables, you have to roll it ALL by hand. Child tables, relationships, etc. Basically, the only DBs I'd recommend using Webflux with is Mongo or Elastic.

@SledgeHammer - I think exactly the same to be honest :))) I'll try my best ti figure out how came that the project started using reactive approach. I'm aware of project loom and of course would rather use it, but being a part of big organization it will take time to adopt java 21... Thank you for your opinion

@MarkBramnik "it will take time" isn't really an option for Webflux unfortunately. Mono.Callable is a work-around for a few blocking OS calls here and there. It's not intended for building an entire application with. If you don't have native reactive support from top to bottom on ALL your dependencies that do I/O, you shouldn't be using Webflux. One of the first things you should do when considering Webflux is to make sure you have reactive support for all I/O.

@MarkBramnik As a side note, various Spring teams have dropped hints that they aren't going to sink major effort into Webflux. The relational driver as I mentioned can't do anything more then 1:1 and the lead has basically said he's not going to do 1:M and M:M support any time soon. Hibernate Reactive also isn't supporting Spring, only Vert.x. That being said, if I was spinning up a new Mongo / Elastic / HTTP service, I'd still go for Webflux. Otherwise, VTs.

Yeah, thanks - I see that traditional relational databases are still not ready to be reactive :) I'll have to figure out why these decisions were taken. Thank you for clarifying about the future of webflux,
